# Divisorial contraction to a non-normal variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, projective-geometry, divisors, resolution-of-singularities

Consider a divisorial contraction $f:X\rightarrow Y$, between projective varieties, contracting an irreducible divisor $D\subset X$ to a subvariety $Z\subset Y$ of codimension at least two, and which an isomorphism from $X\setminus D$ to $Y\setminus Z$. Assume that $X$ is normal.

What is an explicit example of such a divisorial contraction such that $Y$ is not normal?

Comment: What is your definition of "divisorial contraction"?  If $X$ is normal, then the morphism $f$ always factors through the normalization of the image of $f$.  How is the induced morphism from $X$ to this normalization a "different contraction" from $f$?

Comment: Yes, it boils down to construct a birational morphism $g:X\rightarrow W$ contracting $D$ onto $S$, where $\nu:W\rightarrow Y$ is the normalization of $Y$, $\nu$ is $1$-to-$1$ and an isomorphism between $W\setminus S$ and $Y\setminus \nu(S)$.

Comment: "Yes, it boils down to construct a birational morphism ..."  I still do not quite understand your definition of "contraction".  In the definition in textbooks on the Minimal Model Program, usually there is a hypothesis that the natural morphism from the structure sheaf of the target to the pushforward of the structure sheaf of the domain is an isomorphism of sheaves.  Under that hypothesis, using the factorization from my comment, automatically $Y$ is normal.  If you are allowing a more general notion of "contraction", please clarify your definition.

Comment: There is a projective surface $Y$ with an isolated non-normal singularity $p$ such that the normalisation $W \rightarrow Y$ is bijective and $W$ is nonsingular. Let $q$ be the unique point of $W$ over $p$, and let $X \rightarrow W$ be the blowup of $q$. Is this the kind of thing you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, an example like this is exactly what I am looking for. With divisorial contraction I do not mean Mori divisorial contraction. Just a morphism mapping a divisor to something of smaller dimension.

Comment: OK, glad it is useful. The surface singularity I refer to is described in affine form in Georges Elencwajg's answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143954/isolated-non-normal-surface-singularity

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: So, in essence your question was if there are any non-normal singularities whose normalization morphism is one-to-one. As soon as you have such an object, then take the normalization and blow up something in the locus where the normalization map is not an isomorphism. A potentially more interesting question is to do this with a *small* morphism. That can be done, too, but you have to pick your example more carefully.